# Overriding default ValidationMessages.properties from hibernate-validation

Tags: spring, bean-validation, hibernate-validator, spring-validator

I'm trying to override the ValidationMessages.properties from default hibernate-validation (5.0.2 version) in a Spring MVC application.

But it keeps using the internal ValidationMessages.properties from jar.

UPDATE: it works (but it should be another way) when I copy the *.properties files to org\hibernate\validator ...

This is my configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.blueliv.search.*"} )
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  static Logger log =LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.class);

  @Override
  public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
      converters.add(new GsonHttpMessageConverter());

      //converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
  }

  @Bean
  public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
      return new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
  }

  @Bean
  public ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver exceptionResolver() {
      return new ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver();
  }

  @Bean
  public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
      LocalValidatorFactoryBean validatorFactoryBean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
      validatorFactoryBean.setValidationMessageSource(getBundle());
      return validatorFactoryBean;
  }


  public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource getBundle(){
      log.debug("get bundle!");
      ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource bundle = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
      bundle.setBasenames("classpath:/i18n/validation/ValidatonMessages");
      return bundle;
  }


  @Override
  public Validator getValidator() {
      return validator();
  }
```

Comment: Where do you try to place your custom ValidationMessages.properties? If it is in the root of the classpath, it should have precedence over the Hibernate Validator built-in one. Your programmatic way works of course as well, but should not be necessary.

Comment: I tried to put the directly in /classes/ValidationMessages.properties with no luck. Only works when I put the on org\hibernate\validator ... overriding the ones in the dependency jar.

Comment: Is it a web application? Can you outline your whole app structure. Btw, what do you mean with dependency jar?